# How update session attribute in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, session, model-view-controller

How to update Session Attributes in Spring MVC? I tried this code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/panel")
@SessionAttributes({"access"})
public class AdminController extends ErrorsController {

private final static String SECURE_ADMIN_PASS = "123123";

@ModelAttribute("access")
public Boolean getAccess() {
    return false;
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/", ""}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminGeneralPage(@ModelAttribute("access") boolean access) {
    if (!access) return "adminPages/enterPassword";
    return "adminPages/home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String enterPassword(@ModelAttribute("access") boolean access,
                            @RequestParam("password") String password, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (password.equals(SECURE_ADMIN_PASS)) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("access", true);
        return "adminPages/home";
    }
    return "adminPages/enterPassword";
}

}
```

My test case:

-open main page

-automatically redirect to page with password form

-enter password

-automatically redirect to main page, all good, page opening

-refresh page

-again demand password

Comment: That is not what `@SessionAttribute` is intended for. Just use session attributes as you normally would for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your enterPassword() method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String enterPassword(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @ModelAttribute("access") boolean access,
                            @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    if (password.equals(SECURE_ADMIN_PASS)) {
        model.addAttribute("access", true);
        return "adminPages/home";
    }
    return "adminPages/enterPassword";
}
```